# Visual Studio 2010 - Curly Braces auto-align has changed, how do I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, curly-braces

Update: Since I see this is one of my most looked at questions, now a few years later I should point out what I found to be the most common cause of this problem: bad syntax elsewhere in your code. 100% of the time I've had this happen, it was because I'd forgotten a curly brace for another block of code, or I had a dangling if, or an earlier line of code I didn't finish. Check for IDE errors first for something like ") or } expected"

Original Question:

I feel like this is an all time dumb question to ask, but I have no idea how to fix this and google is turning up nothing.

In visual studio, when I type:

```
try {

}
```

VS would automatically reformat it to

```
try
{

}
```

But now it's just leaving it at the first one. I assume I accidentally hit a hotkey or something. Help me fix this please?

Comment: Since my answer is about VB.NET express and I'm not sure it's the solution I'm gonna say it as a comment:
Go to: Tools -> Options -> mark "show all settings" -> Text Editor -> Basic -> Try playing with the Indenting options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9 times out of 10 this problem is caused by bad code elsewhere on my document. Either I'm missing a `;` on a line, or perhaps a closing `}`. Visual Studio is unable to figure out what I'm trying to write in code and thus it's unable to format. Check for compiler errors, fix them, and then press `Ctrl+K` then `Ctrl + D` to make Visual Studio reformat the current document (your hotkeys may vary, depending on the version of Visual Studio and your settings).

Answer (score 3):

Tools->Options

Click Text Editor -> Whatever language -> Formatting

Answer (score 1):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C# (or whatever language)->Formatting->New Lines

Select the options you want.

If you have [Power Commands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) installed you can then go to the Tools->Options->Power Commands and make sure "Format Document on Save" is selected.

Whenever you save the edited file the Curly Braces will be auto aligned.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the default Visual Studio settings mentioned, for [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) users, this is configured via:

ReSharper [menu] -> Options

In the Options dialog, navigate to Environment -> Editor -> Editor Behavior -> "Auto-format on closing brace". See image:

[image]